# Does "wealth" only refers to a financial aspect?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

For a contest I'm attenting, the organisators uses, in their theme description, the world `wealth`. I wonder of the meaning of this word...

Here is the sentenc where it's used :

> Europe need to position themselves in this race for inventions and services to safeguard the **wealth** of their population in a globalized world.

Is it to be understood only by a financial aspect ?

Comment: Yes, it refers to economic wealth.

Comment: In that context, yes, it is used in the financial sense, i.e. in terms of capital and other assets fungible with capital. In the broader sense, one can talk about *one's true wealth being his family*, that *health is wealth*, and so on. But, as I said, in your particular sentence, it means the Europeans' *stuff*.